# How to filter elasticsearch results given a range?

Tags: elasticsearch, range

This is a follow up question for [How to derive a field from two fields in an Elasticsearch index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195303/how-to-derive-a-field-from-two-fields-in-an-elasticsearch-index)

How can I filter the result *hour_bucket.buckets[]* by a range(example only 10 to 12)

Example, If fields *start_date=9* and *end_date=11*, *hour_bucket.bucket[]* should have "key": 10 and "key": 11(desregarding 9).

Expected result should be:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "room_bucket" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "room_V",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "hour_bucket" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 11,
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : 12,
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "room_Y",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "hour_bucket" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 10,
                "doc_count" : 2
              },
              {
                "key" : 11,
                "doc_count" : 2
              },
              {
                "key" : 12,
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Here is the current query:

```
curl -XGET "https://localhost:9200/testindex/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "room_bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "room_name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hour_bucket": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {
              "inline": """
              return LongStream.rangeClosed(doc.start_date.value, doc.end_date.value).toArray();

""",
              "lang": "painless"
            },
            "order": {
              "_key": "asc"
            },
            "value_type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building up on the solution of the referenced thread, we can add parameters to the script in the aggregation section to further filter the aggregated results:

```
curl -XGET "https://localhost:9200/testindex/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "room_bucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "room_name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hour_bucket": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {
              "inline": """
              def range = LongStream.rangeClosed(doc.start_date.value, doc.end_date.value);
              return range.filter(x -> x >= params.min && x <= params.max).toArray();

""",
              "lang": "painless",
              "params": {
                "min": 10,
                "max": 11
              }
            },
            "order": {
              "_key": "asc"
            },
            "value_type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```